# Permission denied in OS X 10.8.2 XCode

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.5

I have 2 targets in my project. The second on is Mac 64-bit. When I run my target on Mac OS 10.7, everything is OK. But in 10.8.2, I can't run my target. It gives this error:

*Could not launch "Takeway", Permission denied*.

Comment: Can you provide more information? You said you have 2 targets, one being 64-bit. Are you trying to run the 32-bit target on 10.7 and the 64-bit target on 10.8.2? Also, what are the permissions on the app bundle and executable inside the bundle?

Comment: my computer are mac 64 bit i use second target for core data. on 10.7 32-bit my target does't work.The Alternate Install permissions are u+w,go-w,a+rX and the target permissions are read and write

Answer (score 0):

Try opening xcode from terminal as
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
See if you still face the issue